# AS3 find x and y of a point in a rotated movieclip

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I have movieclip with a point in it: `.x = 20 .y = 20` when I do `trace("x="_root.movieclip.point.x)` it will trace `x=20`.

But if I rotate movieclip to 90 degres, `x` have to be `-20`, but it still traces `x=20`.

Is it possible to do that?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The point object is local to the MovieClip. If you change attributes of the MovieClip, the child Objects do not change in their "local" space. Much like if you moved the MovieClip to (100,100), the point Object will still be (20,20). You may be able to use the [localToGlobal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#localToGlobal%28%29) and/or [globalToLocal](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html#globalToLocal%28%29) methods to determine the point's modified position.